# Attach dynamic events to elements with Jquery On (using jquery plugins on dynamic elements)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know you can attach events using

```
$(selector).on("click", "#myelement", function()
{ ... 
}).
```

but I want to do something like this:

```
$("body").on("tagsinput", "#myelement", function()
{ ... 
}).
```

I want my dynamic element  "#myelement" to use tagsinput plugin when it is in the DOM

mainly I used jquery plugins  when the element is already in the DOM like this:

```
$(function (){ $("#myelement").tagsinput(); });
```

Help help!  :D

Comment: You generally can't attach a plugin to elements that don't exist. You have to wait until the elements are inserted, *and then* call the plugin on them

Comment: Unless you are writing this plugin and it doesn't require dom manipulation prior to any events occurring...then you could delegate all the event handling to a selector that does exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could initialise tagsinput (if it exists) when the user clicks on the element, which I think will solve your problem.

```
$(document).on("click", "#myelement", function() {
  // don't add the functionality twice
  if ($(this).data("tagsinput-initialised")) return;

  // don't try to add functionality if plugin hasn't loaded
  if ($.isFunction($.fn.tagsInput)) {
    // "save" that we've applied the functionality
    $(this).data("tagsinput-initialised", true);
    // do it
    $(this).tagsinput();
  }
});
```